# Wordpress, default_term parameter for register_taxonomy, checkbox not visually checked

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

With **Wordpress 5.5** came the new `default_term` parameter for `register_taxonomy()`, [enabling you to define a default pre-selected term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#parameters).

- *Source @ https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/29/miscellaneous-developer-focused-changes-in-wordpress-5-5/#post-82881*

It seems that, if you insert a term into a custom taxonomy, using `wp_insert_term()` and then define it as default, the visual checkbox aspect of that default term, under "publishing a new post", in the Wordpress admin panel, won't update. Meaning you won't see the term checkbox checked, but it is.

Also, if you remove a default term from `default_term` the database won't update. You have to manually remove it from phpMyAdmin OR use delete_option.

Did anybody experienced the same issue, and what was your work-around?

Comment: An existing ticket is apparently open. @see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51666.